# Unable to initialize the dbcontext with initial data in code first entity model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on asp.net mvc. I am trying to implement Code-First Entity Model. I have follwed the following steps,

1, I have created a class student.cs

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string Branch { get; set; }
    public decimal Marks { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

2, I have craeted context class like,

```
 public class StudentContext:DbContext
    {
        public StudentContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new StudentContextInitializer());
        }

        public DbSet<Student> Student { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
```

3, I have created studentcontextinitializer class like,

```
public class StudentContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<StudentContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(StudentContext context)
        {
            context.Student.Add(new Student { StudentName="madhav",Branch="CSE",Marks=888,Address="AKP" });
            context.Student.Add(new Student { StudentName = "Tirumalesh", Branch = "IT", Marks = 988, Address = "MDP" });
            context.Student.Add(new Student { StudentName = "Venkat", Branch = "ECE", Marks = 1000, Address = "BZA" });
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I am successfully connected to database but i am unable to initialize the dbcontext with some data that means I have hard coded some records in studentcontextinitializer class but i am unable to bind that records into database table. so please guide me.

Comment: Drop your db and try again. Either that, or extend from DropCreateDatabaseAlwaysInitializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` will only initialize the db when you change the model. You have a couple of options:

1. Delete the database manually and re-run.
2. Change a model property. For example, add `public string test { get; set; }` to your `Student` entity and re-run.
3. Extend your initializer from `DropCreateDatabaseAlwaysInitializer`. This will cause the db to be deleted, recreated, and seeded each time you rebuild and re-run your app.